# Vuepress not registering a service worker

Tags: vuepress

I'm in the process of porting my website over to vuepress but I can't seem to get the service worker running. [The Docs](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/config/#serviceworker) say I just need to set the `serviceWorker` boolean in the config to `true`. So I did that, and it generated a service worker for me. But it won't register.

After a while of digging though the minified code and setting some breakpoints, I found the line that registers the service worker.

```
Go.router.onReady(function () {
    Qo.$mount("#app"),
        "https:" === window.location.protocol && Xo("/vuepress-blog/service-worker.js", {
            ready: function () {
                console.log("[vuepress:sw] Service worker is active."),
                    Qo.$refs.layout.$emit("sw-ready")
            },
            cached: function () {
                console.log("[vuepress:sw] Content has been cached for offline use."),
                    Qo.$refs.layout.$emit("sw-cached")
            },
            updated: function () {
                console.log("[vuepress:sw] Content updated."),
                    Qo.$refs.layout.$emit("sw-updated")
            },
            offline: function () {
                console.log("[vuepress:sw] No internet connection found. App is running in offline mode."),
                    Qo.$refs.layout.$emit("sw-offline")
            },
            error: function (t) {
                console.error("[vuepress:sw] Error during service worker registration:", t),
                    Qo.$refs.layout.$emit("sw-error", t)
            }
        })
})
```

It's been obfuscated, so I'm not entirely sure what the `Go` and `Qo` variables are, but it seems to try and register a service worker when the router's `onReady` event is fired. However, this event is never fired.

This is where I get stuck. I have absolutely no idea why this function wouldn't be fired.

The repo for this project is publicly available [on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/samdbeckham/vuepress-blog) and is deployed on [GitLab Pages](http://samdbeckham.gitlab.io/vuepress-blog/). I'd really appreciate some help on this one.